# How to always rotate an element clockwise with normalized angle and transition?

Tags: javascript, rotation, css-animations, transition

I am trying to make a simple game in which you can rotate each element by 90 degrees on each click with some transition like 500ms. When it passes from 270 to 0 it goes in opposite direction. It is possible to achieve this by keeping incrementing the value to +Infinity, but what if I want to keep the angle normalized, from 0 to 359? How do I tell browser to use closest path to rotate an object basically going from 270 to 360 and not from 270 to 0. What if someday I exceed the integer limit and it brakes? Is it even possible? Here is an example of how it works right now.

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img")

for(const image of images) {
  let rotation = 0;

  image.style.transition = 'transform 500ms';

  image.addEventListener('click', function() {
    rotation = (rotation + 90) % 360
    image.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation}deg)`
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to mod the angle by 360. Integer limit in JS is about 9007199254740991. So if you rotate 100 times per second, it's still would last 100,000 years or so.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img")

for(const image of images) {
  let rotation = 0;

  image.style.transition = 'transform 500ms';

  image.addEventListener('click', function() {
    rotation = (rotation + 90)
    image.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation}deg)`
  })
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
```